# Wrapfig doesn't work in the environment proof

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I need to put an illustration in a proof in one of my document. Since it's a small image, I would like to put it surrounded by the text, using the environment wrapfigure.

Yet, the text doesn't wrap around the image in the environment proof whereas it does outside of the proof.

Does anyone know if this is an issue or if it's possible to still have the text wrapped around the image in a proof ?

Example:

```
\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example.png}
\caption{test}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-3]
Thus, $e$ is unique.
\end{proof}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to include a working example of the problem being asked.

Comment: That is normal, since theorem-like environments are implemented as lists, and `wrapfig` does not behave well in the neighbourhood of lists. There exist workarounds, though. Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?